# @id is putting query parameters in alphabetical order in resource

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have been stuck in this issue

```
$resource(BASE_URL, {
        snId: '@snId',
        id: '@id',
      },
```

i am passing parametrs in this order in query

```
'request_type':$stateParams['request_type'],
          'screen_name': 'abx',
          'graph_type': 'dddd',
          'hide_users': 0,
          'auto_tag' : 0
```

I should get url as `activity?request_type=abc&screen_name=abx&graph_type=dddd&hide_users=0&auto_tag=0` but instead of this i am getting url in alphabetical order as

```
auto_tag=0…hide_users=0&request_type=abc&screen_name=abx
```

Hope anybody knowing this can help

Comment: is @id is putting them in alphabetically ? Are there any other options ?

Comment: dont rely on order, thats a flaw